# How to split up an array by unique keys?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, unique, element

I am finding the lowest value in the array "value" using a min function.  The lowest value is assigned a 1, all else 0.  I have several descriptive column variables: drug, size, strength, form, time.  I want to find the min value of each unique key rather than the lowest value in the entire array "value".

I have tried running loops for each column variable.

```
def min_mask(arr):
    m = np.min(arr)
    return np.vectorize(lambda x: x == m)(arr).astype(int)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_arr = np.array(meltDF["value"])
    print(min_mask(my_arr))
```

Comment: So what is your problem exactly? Do you get an error?

Comment: A sample input and output, as well as desired output, would be helpful here. Your question is somewhat unclear.

Comment: Comparisons (like most operations on arrays) are vectorized, so the last line of the function can just be `return (x==m).astype(int)`

Answer (score 0):

There are many options here, for example:

1) Pre-initialize the mask and use `argmin` to fill in the appropriate places:

```
arr = np.random.rand(10, 4)
indices = np.argmin(arr, axis=0)
mask = np.zeros_like(arr, dtype=np.int)
mask[indices, range(len(indices))] = 1
```

2) Using `apply_along_axis` is probably the style you prefer:

```
def is_minimum(v):
    return v == np.min(v)

mask = np.apply_along_axis(is_minimum, axis=0, arr=arr).astype(np.int)
```

These solutions assume that each column corresponds to a unique key.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I will use apply_along_axis.  So helpful, bless

Comment: How would I go about specifying which columns correspond to a unique key?  Is it in the arr= option?

Comment: @SeabassJohn Have you looked at your dataframe? Are any of the variables ("drug", "length", etc) repeated? If not, there is nothing to worry about. If there are columns with the same name, I would rename them, as having the same name for different variables is just bad practice. Either way, we are starting to discuss a new issue here, and one that isn't really a programming problem per se. If this answer (or the other one) solves your problem as stated in your question, then accept it. If you have other issues, open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare elements to their column-wise mins, then case to uint8 to save a bit of space:

```
>>> import numpy as np                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
>>> np.random.seed(444)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
>>> arr = np.random.rand(10, 4)                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
>>> (arr == arr.min(axis=0)).astype(np.uint8)                                                                                                                                                                                                           
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0]], dtype=uint8)
```

---

Because of NumPy's [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html), the comparison `arr == arr.min(axis=0)` will produce a result that is the same shape of `arr`, even though `arr.min(axis=0)` will have shape `(4,)`.

Note that if columns have duplicate minimums, this may generate more than one "1" in a single column.